# How to fix "spawn UNKNOWN" Error in Electron?

Tags: npm, electron, yarnpkg

I built an Electron app on 64-bit windows machine and it runs well on other machines.

But today, I ran it on my 32-bit atom processor windows machine and I got the following error message.

I tried npm update but it doesn't work too.

the error message is,

[image]

How can I fix it? : (
Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access rights. Try running as an administrator or change permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may try checking, if antivirus has blocked this process.